# Is it possible to suppress MSB warnings in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Please, note - if you propose to call `msbuild` with `/nowarn:MSB...` switch, then you should also explain how to make Visual Studio pass this flag to msbuild, because I am specifically asking about suppressing warnings when building in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use this in `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>

<MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>MSBxxx</MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>

</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I have not forgotten. Just caught up in other things at work.

Comment: Okay.And we will wait for your any reponse:)

Comment: Seems to work. I may have more results as I am progressing with my work.